# Why should I use key as string for list item in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

React Doc explains why giving a key to list item is important. It specifies that a key is string attribute.

So should I convert my id to string for key every time?

```
<ul>
  {data.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id.toString()}>
      {item.text}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could you tell me the reason for this? I thought about problem with number sort as strings but it seemed to be another case.

React Doc. [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)

Comment: Did you find an answer? I too don't understand why they use toString()...

Answer (score 5):

Key is fundamental for the React to index a list in the render process (in the background). If you don't put the key, you get this:

[image]

This simply means that he needs to look for the component, what will take longer.

To solve the toString(), to this:

```
key={`OperationTesterInput_${idx}`
```

Looks much more cleaner. You can also use the index parameter present in the map function, also does the trick :)

**The Reason why its a string**

It is not. The reason is because of typescript. The implementation is the following:

[image]

So following this implementation, this is valid:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but what is the reason of a string type for a key?

Comment: Its none. The reason is complaining its because you are using typescript. just see the implementation of the key prop. Its literally this: key?: Key | null. And key is: type Key = string | number. So test it out: key={1 as Key}

Comment: You're right, but React Doc examples are written in Javascript, and they use `id.toString()` or `i.toString()` converting. It seems to be a some kind of React idea, not Typescript.

Comment: All the majors implementations are build in typescript nowadays (for obvious reasons). The update was added above

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Key is used so that if an element changes or is removed, React only needs to rerender that specific element rather than the whole list. This key is required to be a string because the HTML attribute values are always strings, whatever value you give must be serialized to a string. We can assign anything to an attribute, but it becomes a string.

Comment: Thank you, I have the same opinion, but why does React team write `id.toString()` in documentation? :-)

Comment: @bigbabyweb because toString() method returns a string for an object property. They want to make sure that `id` must be converted into `string` data type.