# Key assigning for re-rendering list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**(Not any commercial thing, I use the brands as an example)**

I am trying to implement a simple watchlist application. For that, I implement a search input area with a result box just below the input(to search stocks). And when I type some stock, for example "apple", I can see the results clearly.

[image]

So after the add "apple" to the watchlist by checking the checkmark, it is added to the watchlist successfully.

[image]

When I search for another stock, for example "nvidia", results are shown successfully, but there is a problem with the checkboxes. It comes with the marked checkbox although it is not in the watchlist as you see.

[image]

SearchResultBox.tsx:

```
import { APISearchResult } from "../../types/ApiSearchResult";
import SearchResultBoxItem from "../search-result-box-item";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

type SearchResultBoxProps = {
  apiSearchResults: APISearchResult | null;
  searchInputRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  searchText: string;
  searchResultBoxRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  error: Error | null;
};

const SearchResultBox: React.FC<SearchResultBoxProps> = ({
  apiSearchResults,
  searchInputRef,
  searchText,
  searchResultBoxRef,
  error,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles["search-bar"]}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        defaultValue={searchText}
        ref={searchInputRef}
      />
      <div className={styles["search-result-box"]} ref={searchResultBoxRef}>
        {error ? (
          <h1>{error.message}</h1>
        ) : (
          apiSearchResults?.ResultSet?.Result.map((result, index) => (
            <SearchResultBoxItem key={index} stock={result} />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResultBox;
```

SearchResultBoxItem.tsx:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { WatchlistContext } from "../../contexts/watchlistContext";
import { StockSearchResult } from "../../types/ApiSearchResult";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";

type SearchResultBoxItemProps = {
  stock: StockSearchResult;
};

const SearchResultBoxItem: React.FC<SearchResultBoxItemProps> = ({ stock }) => {
  const checkboxRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const context = useContext(WatchlistContext);

  if (!context) {
    return (
      <p>We are having a problem with the watchlist. Please try again later.</p>
    );
  }

  const { addToWatchlist, removeFromWatchlist, watchlist } = context;

  const isChecked = (stock: StockSearchResult) => {
    return watchlist.some((s) => s.symbol === stock.symbol);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkboxRef.current) {
      const checkboxObservable$ = fromEvent(checkboxRef.current, "change");
      const checkboxObserver = {
        next: (e: Event) => {
          const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
          if (target.checked) {
            addToWatchlist(stock);
          } else {
            removeFromWatchlist(stock);
          }
        },
        error: (err: Error) => console.log(err),
        complete: () => console.log("complete"),
      };

      const checkboxSubscription =
        checkboxObservable$.subscribe(checkboxObserver);

      //clean up when unmount
      return () => checkboxSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles["info-box-item"]}>
      <div className={styles.left}>
        <h4>{stock.name}</h4>
        <p className={styles.silent}>{stock.symbol}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.right}>
        <div className={styles.info}>
          <h4>{stock.exch}</h4>
          <p className={styles.silent}>{stock.type}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={stock.symbol}
            className={styles.toggle}
            defaultChecked={isChecked(stock)}
            ref={checkboxRef}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResultBoxItem;
```

**I am clearly aware the reason** why this is happening: I am assigning keys to indexes and when indexes are equal, React cannot understand the difference between the components.

When I assign `stock.stmbol` to the key problem is solved. But I am also know that, assigning key to some string value is also not great. So, is there another way, assigning
keys differently, without breaking this code?

Comment: You say "I also know that assigning a key to some string value is also not great".  Why?  That's perfectly fine and what I would do (assuming the reasonable case that you want the stocks to be unique in your list).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I use key as string for list item in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835541/why-should-i-use-key-as-string-for-list-item-in-react)